# missing kubectl config files after install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes

I tried to install kubectl on popos using the following commands

```
sudo apt install -y ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https
sudo curl -fsSLo /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y kubectl
```

After the installation `kubectl cluster-info` give me that

```
kalin@pop-os:~$ kubectl cluster-info
E0304 00:04:05.721040   93361 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0304 00:04:05.721478   93361 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0304 00:04:05.722950   93361 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0304 00:04:05.724685   93361 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0304 00:04:05.726373   93361 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

helm status RELEASE_NAME give me that

```
kalin@pop-os:~$ helm status RELEASE_NAME
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "http://localhost:8080/version": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Not sure if that is the reason but it's turnout that I don't have `~/.kube/config` or `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`. I made a lot of google searches but at that point I surrender

Comment: `kubectl` is the client and the configuration file is generated in `k8s`, not `kubectl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's turnout that the installation of kubectl don't provide kubernetes cluster itself. After some googling I find out that I need to install more components on my system. There are at least 4 possible options for local kubernetes cluster

- [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)
- [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/)
- [crc](https://github.com/crc-org/crc)
- [minishift](https://github.com/minishift/minishift)

It seems that minikube is the simplest and I didn't explore the rest. Also if you install minukube you may not need to install kubectl because minikube provide one

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of `k8s`  ?

Port 8080 is not supported in higher versions, you need to use 6443.

`kubectl` version and `k8s` version

Are kubelet and kube-apiserver compatible ?

https://kubernetes.io/releases/version-skew-policy/#kubelet

> kubelet must not be newer than kube-apiserver, and may be up to two minor versions older.

```
Example:

kube-apiserver is at 1.26
kubelet is supported at 1.26, 1.25, and 1.24
```

If your configuration file is in the correct location, the kubectl version is also correct. You can troubleshoot this in the way given below

```bash
┌──[root@vms100.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible/falco]
└─$kubectl cluster-info -v=1
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://192.168.26.99:30033
CoreDNS is running at https://192.168.26.99:30033/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
┌──[root@vms100.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible/falco]
└─$kubectl cluster-info -v=9
I0304 23:00:23.406007  117409 loader.go:374] Config loaded from file:  /root/.kube/config
I0304 23:00:23.430565  117409 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.25.1 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/e4d4e1a" 'https://192.168.26.99:30033/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services?labelSelector=kubernetes.io%2Fcluster-service%3Dtrue'
I0304 23:00:23.433095  117409 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:192.168.26.99:30033 succeed
I0304 23:00:23.447398  117409 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://192.168.26.99:30033/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services?labelSelector=kubernetes.io%2Fcluster-service%3Dtrue 200 OK in 16 milliseconds
I0304 23:00:23.447454  117409 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 1 ms TLSHandshake 6 ms ServerProcessing 7 ms Duration 16 ms
I0304 23:00:23.447464  117409 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I0304 23:00:23.447474  117409 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid: 428a4a76-922c-4451-ba2d-74bc231f896c
I0304 23:00:23.447482  117409 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid: dfc65bb0-fb29-4499-bdbb-420ace44c285
I0304 23:00:23.447510  117409 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Length: 1676
I0304 23:00:23.447518  117409 round_trippers.go:580]     Date: Sat, 04 Mar 2023 15:00:23 GMT
I0304 23:00:23.447545  117409 round_trippers.go:580]     Audit-Id: c67e042d-7506-448a-b709-369410528d11
I0304 23:00:23.447557  117409 round_trippers.go:580]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I0304 23:00:23.447565  117409 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Type: application/json
I0304 23:00:23.447770  117409 request.go:1154] Response Body: {"kind":"ServiceList","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"resourceVersion":"7355757"},"items":[{"metadata":{"name":"kube-dns","namespace":"kube-system","uid":"ec55d5bf-be92-461f-bbda-8d8a694eb25a","resourceVersion":"256","creationTimestamp":"2023-01-26T11:28:00Z","labels":{"k8s-app":"kube-dns","kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true","kubernetes.io/name":"CoreDNS"},"annotations":{"prometheus.io/port":"9153","prometheus.io/scrape":"true"},"managedFields":[{"manager":"kubeadm","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2023-01-26T11:28:00Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:annotations":{".":{},"f:prometheus.io/port":{},"f:prometheus.io/scrape":{}},"f:labels":{".":{},"f:k8s-app":{},"f:kubernetes.io/cluster-service":{},"f:kubernetes.io/name":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:clusterIP":{},"f:internalTrafficPolicy":{},"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"port\":53,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:port":{},"f:protocol":{},"f:targetPort":{}},"k:{\"port\":53,\"protocol\":\"UDP\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:port":{},"f:protocol":{},"f:targetPort":{}},"k:{\"port\":9153,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:port":{},"f:protocol":{},"f:targetPort":{}}},"f:selector":{},"f:sessionAffinity":{},"f:type":{}}}}]},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"dns","protocol":"UDP","port":53,"targetPort":53},{"name":"dns-tcp","protocol":"TCP","port":53,"targetPort":53},{"name":"metrics","protocol":"TCP","port":9153,"targetPort":9153}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"kube-dns"},"clusterIP":"10.96.0.10","clusterIPs":["10.96.0.10"],"type":"ClusterIP","sessionAffinity":"None","ipFamilies":["IPv4"],"ipFamilyPolicy":"SingleStack","internalTrafficPolicy":"Cluster"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}}]}
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://192.168.26.99:30033
CoreDNS is running at https://192.168.26.99:30033/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
┌──[root@vms100.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible/falco]
└─$
```